# Path colouring in google maps

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I wanted to know if is it possible to change the colors of the path displayed in the Google Maps APIv3 specially in the TRANSIT section where different using modes like BUS, RAIL and WALKING are used for displaying the result.

Can I change the displayed color of these different modes? Currently it is Black for walking and sky blue for other modes.

My code is:

```
function calcRouteM() 
{
    var start = document.getElementById('DropDownList1').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('DropDownList2').value;
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
        transitOptions: {
              departureTime: new Date(1362799800000)
        }
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colors of the Polylines if you don't use the DirectionsRenderer to display them and render them yourself.

The [DirectionsRendererOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)  `{suppressPolylines: false}`

> suppressPolylines | boolean | Suppress the rendering of polylines.

Then process through the results object creating Polylines with your desired colors.

[Example of custom rendering a route](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html) (you probably only need to do the polyline)

Another option might be (not tested) to post process the returned route, sending the different colored pieces to different DirectionsRenderer calls with different values (colors) for the polylineOptions option.

Comment: It would be really great if you can provide me with an example.
I'm putting my code in my above asked question Please look into it.

Comment: If you want a complete example, provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.